# Потоки в Linux - C++ Linux

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Что-то не-то с кодом. не выводятся предыдущие потоки с соответствующими  надписями и не удаляются(( Ломаю голову 2 дня!

```
#define _REENTRANT
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_COUNT 10
#define KEY 1234

char strings[10][30] =
{
    {"\r\nFirst process"},{"\r\nSecond process"}, {"\r\nThird process"}, {"\r\nFourth process"},
    {"\r\nFifth process"} ,{"\r\nSixth process"},{"\r\nSeventh process"},{"\r\nEighth process"},
    {"\r\nNinth process"},{"\r\nTenth process"},
};

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int index1;

struct someArg
{
    int index;
} someAgruments;

void *thread_function(void * arg)
{
    index1 = *(int *) arg;

    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);//захват глобальной переменной-никто не получит ресурс до освобожения

        std::cout << index1 << std::endl;

            std::cout << strings[index1-1] << std::endl;
            sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);//освобождаем ресурс-другие могут с ним работать
    }

}

int main()
{
    int sizeOfThreads = 0;
    int res;
    void *thread_result;
    pthread_t threads[MAX_COUNT];

    /*создаем мьютекс*/
    if(!(pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL)))
        perror("pthread_mutex_init");

    ///////////////ncurses/////////////////
    initscr();//переход в curses режим
    clear();//очиска экрана
    noecho();//печатные символы не отображаются
    refresh();//проверяет буфер и если он не пуст-отправляет информацию на экран

      std::cout << "Press '+' for add process.\r\nPress '-' for kill process.\r\nPress 'q' for exit program.\n";

      char c;

      while(c != 'q')
      {
          switch(c = getchar())
              {
                  case '+'://добавить процесс
                  {
                      if(sizeOfThreads < MAX_COUNT)
                          sizeOfThreads++;

                      if((res = pthread_create(
                                        &threads[sizeOfThreads],//id нового потока
                                        NULL,//поток создан с стандартными атрибутами
                                        thread_function,//указатель на потоковую функцию
                                        &sizeOfThreads//значение аргумента потока
                                        )) < 0)//если поток создан успешно- функция возвращает 0

                          perror("pthread_create");
                  }

                  break;

                  case '-':// удалить процесс
                  {
                      if(sizeOfThreads == 0)
                          std::cout << "\r\nSorry, but your delete all threads!\r\n";

                      else
                      {
                          pthread_join(threads[sizeOfThreads], NULL);
                          sizeOfThreads--;

                          std::cout << "\r\nKill thread!\r\n" << std::endl;
                          refresh();
                      }
                  }

                  break;
              }

          refresh();
      }

      //завершаем все дочерние процессы
      if(threads[sizeOfThreads] != 0)
      {
          for(; sizeOfThreads> 0; sizeOfThreads--)
          {
              pthread_join(threads[sizeOfThreads], NULL);
          }

           refresh();
           sleep(2);
      }

      clear();
      endwin();//выход из режима curses

      return 0;
}
```

Вот задание:

*Исходный процесс является управляющим, принимает поток ввода с клавиатуры и контролирует потоки. По нажатию клавиши ‘+’ добавляется новый поток, ‘-’ – удаляется последний добавленный, ‘q’ – программа завершается. Каждый поток посимвольно выводит на экран в вечном цикле свою уникальную строку. При этом операция вывода строки должна быть атомарной, т.е. процесс вывода должен быть синхронизирован таким образом, чтобы строки на экране не перемешивались. В качестве метода синхронизации следует использовать мутекс.*

Answer (score 2):

И правильно не удаляются. Читайте документацию: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

> The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread
>          to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then
>          pthread_join() returns immediately.  The thread specified by thread
>          must be joinable.

А у вас что? Вы никак конкретному потоку не даёте указания завершиться, он продолжает вертеться в бесконечном цикле. Передавайте каждому потоку свою структуру в качестве аргумента, где, так же, передавайте флаг завершения:

```
...
struct ThreadParameters
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    bool keep;
    // some other stuff
};

void init_thread_parameters(ThreadParameters &params)
{
    params = ThreadParameters();
    if (!pthread_mutex_init(&params.mutex, 0))
        perror("init_thread_parameters:pthread_mutex_init");
    params.keep = true;
    // init other stuff
}

void request_thread_stop(ThreadParameters &params)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&params.mutex);
    params.keep = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&params.mutex);
}

bool check_thread_stop(ThreadParameters &params)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&params.mutex);
    bool doStop = !params.keep;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&params.mutex);    
    return doStop;
}

...
void *thread_function(void * arg)
{
    //index1 = *(int *) arg;
    ThreadParameters *params = static_cast<ThreadParameters*>(arg);
    assert(params != 0);

    while(1)
    {
        // some code
        ...
        // some code
        if (check_thread_stop(*params))
            break;
    }
}
...
int main()
{
    ...
    pthread_t        threads[MAX_COUNT];
    ThreadParameters threadParams[MAX_COUNT];
    ...
                  case '+'://добавить процесс
                  {
                      if(sizeOfThreads < MAX_COUNT)
                          sizeOfThreads++;

                      // Инициализируем параметры для потока
                      ThreadParameters *params = &threadParams[sizeOfThreads];
                      init_thread_parameters(*params);

                      if((res = pthread_create(
                                        &threads[sizeOfThreads],//id нового потока
                                        NULL,//поток создан с стандартными атрибутами
                                        thread_function,//указатель на потоковую функцию
                                        params//значение аргумента потока
                                        )) < 0)//если поток создан успешно- функция возвращает 0

                          perror("pthread_create");
                  }

                  break;

                  case '-':// удалить процесс
                  {
                      if(sizeOfThreads == 0)
                          std::cout << "\r\nSorry, but your delete all threads!\r\n";

                      else
                      {
                          // Запрашиваем останов конкретного потока
                          request_thread_stop(threadParams[sizeOfThreads]);

                          pthread_join(threads[sizeOfThreads], NULL);
                          sizeOfThreads--;

                          std::cout << "\r\nKill thread!\r\n" << std::endl;
                          refresh();
                      }
                  }

                  break;
              }

          refresh();
      }

      //завершаем все дочерние процессы
      if(threads[sizeOfThreads] != 0)
      {
          for(; sizeOfThreads> 0; sizeOfThreads--)
          {
              // Запрашиваем останов конкретного потока
              request_thread_stop(threadParams[sizeOfThreads]);
              pthread_join(threads[sizeOfThreads], NULL);
          }

...
      }

...
}
```

код не собирал, просто показать принцип.

Comment: благодарю. тема сложная.  вечером попробую пофиксить.

Comment: Вы для каждого потока создаете свой мьютекс. Синхронизации не будет

Comment: @PavelParshin, судя по всему, вы невнимательно смотрели. Этот мутекс нужен для защиты переменной keep, доступ к которой производится из двух потоков. Не видите, из каких?

Comment: @MonahTuk, ок, понял вас